# Using MongoDB for time-series data: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mongodb

Following [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22129593/688869), I am currently planning to migrate a time-series database to MongoDB. Note that I am a complete **newbie** to MongoDB and NoSQL databases in general.

The current schema is rather simple. I have about **15000 unique datapoints**, identified by a 31 bit integer. Each of them has **a few million values**, that are linked to a 32 bit timestamp (UNIX epoch), both together being the *primary key* in the old database schema. Values are either stored as a float or as an 32 bit signed integer, depending on the datapoint ID.

There can't be more than 1 value per timestamp and datapoint, however it must be possible to **overwrite an existing value** (for the same timestamp and datapoint), even though that doesn't happen frequently.

Inserts to the database must be fast (at least 1k inserts / second) but it is even more important that data can be read back quickly, aggregating a large number of values. Even if it would be very interesting, it is **not** necessary to combine different datapoints when aggregating, meaning that all datapoints are independent to each other.

Studying numerous websites on the topic I came to the conclusion that I need a single collection, holding a single document per value. That looks like this:

```
> db.dplog.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6681c"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321625628, "val" : 3.5265 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6705c"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321627740, "val" : 3.5775 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec67513"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321628947, "val" : 3.6085 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec68100"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321632000, "val" : 3.6795 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec68568"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321633128, "val" : 3.715 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec686dc"), "dpid" : 4, "ts" : 1321633500, "val" : 3.6995 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec688cf"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321633999, "val" : 3.5975 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec68c5b"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321634907, "val" : 3.4955 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec68e74"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321635444, "val" : 3.3915 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec69087"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321635975, "val" : 3.2915 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec69294"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321636500, "val" : 3.1945 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6946a"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321636970, "val" : 3.099 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec69474"), "dpid" : 5, "ts" : 1321636980, "val" : 3.1035 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec694b0"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321637040, "val" : 3.0945 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6968d"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321637517, "val" : 2.997 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec698ac"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321638060, "val" : 2.8995 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec69ac8"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321638600, "val" : 2.7955 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec69c6c"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321639020, "val" : 2.8 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6a374"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321640820, "val" : 2.8485 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("00000000000004004ec6aa7c"), "dpid" : 6, "ts" : 1321642620, "val" : 2.891 }
has more
```

Is that schema choosen wisely?

### Concerns about primary key

I am setting the primary key `_id` manually, based on the datapoint ID and timestamp, since that fits easily in those 24 nibbles. I thought, this way I can easily overwrite existing values:

```
$coll->batchInsert([ 1000 documents ], ["continueOnError"=>true]);
```

In my understanding `continueOnError` should handle index collision (at least while migrating existing data), however it creates an exception when the document key exists already:

```
 Uncaught exception 'MongoDuplicateKeyException' with message 'localhost:27017: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: projpf.dplog.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('00000000000004004f4f91fc') }'
```

### Concerns about insert speed

I found inserts of single documents to be rather slow, in contrast to batchInsert(), which can handle about 50k inserts / second on a rather busy test server. I can manage to work with batchInsert(), but how can I implement the **insert-or-replace-existing behavior** when batch-inserting?

### Concerns about read speed

With a test dataset with about 30 million documents (values), a simple read like

```
db.dplog.find({dpid:89, ts : {$gt:1320935476, $lt:1320936479}});
```

that returns no more than 19 documents takes about 8 seconds. This seems extremely **slow** to me.

**Update:** Fixed by adding an index: `db.dplog.ensureIndex({dpid:1,ts:1}, {unique:true, name:"DPValueIndex", sparse:true});`, which makes the query blazing fast.

*Database: MongoDB v2.6.3 64bit; build info: Linux build12.nj1.10gen.cc 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49*

Comment: Have you considered using time interval buckets, with a document for each one, ie, a document per minute, per 10 minutes, per hour, whatever best fits your data volumes. Much of the reading I have done on time series in MongoDB suggests this is a good approach. Also, have you considered storing aggregates for past time periods  -- if you are only interested in high, avg and low, this might be a big time saving, as you would only need to store number of records, high, low and avg, to be able to recompute an average over a different time period.

Comment: I'd like to keep the data *for a single datapoint* in one document, as I need to do dynamic analysis with varying intervals. I could, however, use a document per datapoint. Don't know if that would be better/worse/useless.

Comment: If you are only interested in one datapoint at a time, I would think data point per document with an index on time would yield major improvement. 8 seconds is pretty awful for the query you describe. As a matter of interest, I missed your original question, did you ever try partitioning on date in MySQL. I got spectacular query improvements from some time series data I had, partitioned on date, and then indexed on something similar to your datapoints (ship positions and movements, for what it is worth).

Comment: Please note my *Update* above regarding read speed. After adding a unique index, the query is very fast. However, I am wondering if the one-collection-per-datapoint has other advantages (storage? backup? upsert speed?)

Comment: Glad about the speed issue (I was somewhat surprised, as you said it was indexed on datapoint and time). Are you going to be using shards and replica sets at all?

Comment: I ask because your datapoint id seems like a good natural shard key. Sharding on datapoint id would spread both inserts and analysis queries across multiple nodes. If you are using replica sets, you could also run your select queries on secondary servers, again reducing load on the primary. I believe this is more natural and easier to manage than having separate collections for each datapoint id and allows you the possibility of running aggregate queries across different ids at some future point.

Comment: I expect sharding/replica sets to be become a necessity *in the future*, but right now a single server should handle the existing data easily. So, yes, I want to make decisions now that will *allow* me to operate a multi-node database sometime, but for the moment a single node will have to handle it all. It's hard to predict when this will happen.

Comment: So, for future proofing, a single collection sounds better, with the possibility of using datapoint id as a shard key.